# nginx fails to connect to upstream backend

Tags: asp.net, docker, nginx

I'm trying to host a website on a Debian server. For this I have set up docker containers for frontend and backend (backend being an aspnet6 API). I am using nginx in another container as a reverse proxy. Nginx is configured to route API-traffic ("domain.com/api/...") to the backend container exposing port 5000.

Using Curl (on the server machine) to retrieve from that API works:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/Oracle
true
```

However trying to connect to that API from my local machine via "domain.com/api/Oracle" results in a 502-Bad Gateway.

nginx logs show that the upstream is the same exact URL i tried with curl before

```
2022/07/21 01:30:08 [error] 30#30: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <localmachineip>, server: unixile.de, request: "GET /api/Oracle HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/Oracle", host: "<serverip>"
```

It is even possible to access the backend api from my local machine directly, just not via the nginx rerouting.
I have tried several different nginx configurations, including explicitly naming an upstream for the backend and routing the location more specifically, none worked, I'm at my wits' end. :(

This is my nginx configuration:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {

    listen 0.0.0.0:80;

    root /var/www/unixile.de/html;

    server_name unixile.de www.unixile.de;
    index index.html;

    location = / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /api {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/api;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nginx is running inside a container `127.0.0.1` points to the container itself, where there is no backend running. Please replace that ip with the name of the backend container.

You also need to [run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) all three containers to be in the same [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/)

Comment: That makes total sense, thank you so much